# submit button not working in a form typo3

Tags: forms, tabs, typo3, extbase

I am facing a critical issue, I have to edit an extension created by someone else, A view in Backend of that extension is using the same tab system used by typo3. 
[image]

so , the redirection is generated somehow using javascript. I was asked to add a search form inside "overview" tab, so I added the fluid code for it like so :

```
<f:form method="post" controller="File" action="search" id="search_form">
```

but when I hit the submit button , the concerned action is never called ... It's been more than 4 hours trying succesless to figure out a solution .

Could you please help me ?

This is what the console log says( too many errors ) !![image]

Comment: How does the generated source code look like? Do the Javascript or networking console of your developer tools reveal something?

Comment: have just added it above

Comment: The missing icons shouldn't be the problem, the `Uncaught TypeError`-entries are probably the problem. In order to get a more accurate position of the errors, try to enable the debug mode of the backend in the install tool. This can be done by either using the "development" configuration preset (available since 6.2), or by setting `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['debug'] = 1;` or `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['debug'] = 1;`